# How do i fix shiny deployment issue in browser when running locally?

Tags: browser, shiny, deployment

I am running into issues deploying my shiny application. In R Studio, it states that the application has been deployed successfully, as per the image below.

[Successful deployment message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FNhY.png)

However, I get "An error has occurred. The application failed to start. Contact the author for more information" when opening the application in the browser (chrome and safari).

[Error in browser version of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xigsD.png)

It also states the application is running on my shiny account.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptLug.png)

Does anyone have any recommendations to what problem is occurring here that prevents the shiny app from being run in a browser? The app runs locally without any issues too.
I have all packages installed and up to date and the file directory is correct. I am not running on an SSL network either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the log file on my shiny app management page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.